# Unable to authenticate a user against database

Tags: php, yii

I have done all the stuff which is required to do authentication but in the `Useridentity` class , I have write following code:

```
$user=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('user-name'=>this->username));
```

but at that point, I got error `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, EXPECTING`. How to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yii isn't going to play well with hyphenated column names, because it tries to map all table columns to magic variables in the class.

Change your column name to use underscores, or anything else without hyphens.

Side note: Yii's creators have classified this as [Won't Fix](https://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=755).

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `$this->username`

```
$user=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('user-name'=>$this->username));
```

Comment: If it's still throwing that same error at that line with my above change then you have a defective php build or something lol. Most likely you have the same error somewhere else in your code besides that line.